# TypeScript: Reference interface in class when using AMD

Tags: interface, requirejs, typescript, amd

I set up everything so far to use TypeScript with requirejs. I tested my scenario with to classes and everything works fine but I fail when I try to use interface definitions.

IComponent.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Actor.ts" />

interface IComponent {
  owner: Actor

  init()
  update(delta: number)
  render()
}
```

Actor.ts:

```
/// <reference path="IComponent.ts" />

class Actor {
    private components: IComponent[] = []

    add(component: IComponent) {
        component.owner = this;
        this.components.push(component);
    }

    remove(component: IComponent) {
        var index = this.components.indexOf(component);
        this.components.splice(index, 1);
    }

    update(delta: number) {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.update(delta));
    }

    render() {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.render());
    }

    init() {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.init());
    }
}

export = Actor
```

I get an error in my IComponent.ts: The symbol 'Actor' could not be found. How can I reference my Actor class from my interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently stands you have a logical circular reference, Actor depends on IComponent and IComponent depends on Actor.

Your `IComponent` interface is little use without your `Actor` class, so my recommended solution would be to place the `IComponent` interface within your `actor.ts` file. This way, the dependency is self-sufficient.

```
export interface IComponent {
    owner: Actor;

    init();
    update(delta: number);
    render();
}

export class Actor {
    private components: IComponent[] = []

    add(component: IComponent) {
        component.owner = this;
        this.components.push(component);
    }

    remove(component: IComponent) {
        var index = this.components.indexOf(component);
        this.components.splice(index, 1);
    }

    update(delta: number) {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.update(delta));
    }

    render() {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.render());
    }

    init() {
        this.components.forEach(c => c.init());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `IComponent` depend on an abstraction of `Actor` rather than on the concrete class (in your case, perhaps an `IActor`. Now your `Actor` depends on IComponent, but that is the end of the chain.

```
export interface IComponent {
    owner: IActor;

    init();
    update(delta: number);
    render();
}

export interface IActor {
    add(component: IComponent);
    remove(component: IComponent);
    update(delta: number);
    render();
    init();
}
```

Hacky Fix:

This resolves the error in the IComponent.ts file, but not in a nice way.

```
import Actor = require('actor');

interface IComponent {
    owner: Actor;

    init();
    update(delta: number);
    render();
}
```